# Handling custom payloads in OneSignal notification

Tags: android, onesignal

I have integrated OneSignal in to my android app to use for push notifications, all is working fine and the notifications come through. However what do i need to change in order to handle these notifications in a custom manner? The receiver needs to parse the JSON payload from the notification and send the user to the correct point in the app based on what is received.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a `NotificationOpenedHandler` class to handle the opening of a notification. See the following example code to set it up.

```
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class YourAppClass extends Application {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
        .init();
   }

  // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is running.
  private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements NotificationOpenedHandler {
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
      try {
        if (additionalData != null) {
          if (additionalData.has("actionSelected"))
            Log.d("OneSignalExample", "OneSignal notification button with id " + additionalData.getString("actionSelected") + " pressed");

          Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Full additionalData:\n" + additionalData.toString());
        }
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

If you need to change which Activity is started when your app is opened see the OneSignal [Changing the open action of a notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations#changing-the-open-action-of-a-notification) instructions.